Effects of and prevention of leaking a private key in an public key encryption scheme
Suppose we have a public key encryption scheme and the private key of the client is stored locally as to never leave the client. But this makes me wonder what would happen when the device of the client gets compromised and the attacker gets hold of the private key in this way.
While the private key of the server can be protected a client possibly can't afford that. So how vulnerable is such a scheme to a client's private key being compromised? Would the client's entire connection with the server get compromised or are there safeguards on the server side for that case?
How is this handled in TLS and similar protocols?

I'm not stating the question is off-topic, but given it's generality it may be more appropriate on security-SE. Among common mitigations of that private-key compromise risk are 1) storing the private key passphrase-encrypted; 2) end-of-validity in public-key certificate; 3) certificate revocation.

@fgrieu Ok, thanks, I'll ask the question there

I haven't seen the question there yet and since this hasn't been closed I've answered instead. If you want to have this migrated to [security.se] then please react below or flag the question. It is probably slightly more on topic there, but it does require you use your same account to access the site.

@MaartenBodewes sorry for late reply. If I'm not mistaken I did ask there. But as I can't find the question in my account, I assume eventually I deleted the question (I can't recall why though). So, thanks for the answer!

Effects on public key encryption
It's simple. In an encryption scheme we'd loose all confidentiality to those attackers that:

have access to the ciphertext and;
have gained access to the private key.

However, in the rest of your question it becomes clear that this is not about such an encryption scheme at all.
Public key encryption and transport security
Public key encryption has a sender and a receiver. This sender / receiver may be different entities, but they could also be the same entity for in-place encryption.
Client and server are roles within a network protocol where the client sets up a connection to a server, after which messages can be exchanged between the two. Usually that means that the client sends a request and the server then sends a response.
Securing these messages is performed using a protocol that offers transport security. This protocol may include public key encryption, but usually it does not, and if it does it usually performs hybrid encryption, where a symmetric key encryption is used to protect the messages. These symmetric keys may however also be established through other means, for instance key agreement or key encapsulation.
TLS with server authentication
In TLS the messages are never encrypted with the public key. Instead, for e.g. RSA_ ciphersuites in TLS 1.2 and earlier the master secret is encrypted using the public key. This (symmetric) master key is then used to derive the (symmetric) session keys, and those are used to encrypt the messages. In this case leaking the private key would cause an eavesdropper to decrypt the master secret, derive the session keys and decrypt the messages. It, of course, also allows the attacker to pose as the server as the capability of decrypting the clients master secret is the main part of server authentication.
TLS 1.2 also contains cipher suites that offer forward security. In that case the asymmetric key pair is never used for encryption. Instead the protocol uses a key pair for authentication through digital signatures and an ephemeral key pair for key agreement to derive the master secret and session keys. This offers forward security as the private keys used for deriving the session keys can be destroyed after the connection has been setup. If this destruction is done correctly then the attacker could only obtain the private authentication key of the server, which would allow the attacker to impersonate that server using an active attack, e.g. by diverting the packets going to the server. TLS 1.3 only allows this scenario, at least for the initial connection setup (session resumption).
TLS with client authentication
If the client uses private keys then those are also just authentication keys. So loosing them would cause an attacker to setup connections to the server, impersonating the client - at least on that level. This is a more tricky situation because the server does usually not validate the network address used; it accepts connections from any location, as long as the client certificate is valid.
This happens in a specific PKI setting, usually there is only one root certificate explicitly installed. This is usually mitigated by using some kind of certificate status protocol and by time-limiting the validity of the key pair. Of course, revoking a certificate does depend on the PKI to be aware that the private key has (possibly) been compromised.
Conclusion
Public key encryption is rarely used in transport protocols nowadays, so the question is based on a bad premise. To see what happens in a protocol if a private key is lost and how this can be mitigated depends entirely on the protocol and / or on the PKI surrounding the protocol.

PS I haven't really indicated how a private key could be protected, there are many ways to do that Passwords, special storage devices, smart cards, TPM's, HSM's (for server-to-server communication), security enclaves on smart phones etc. Those are generally not directly not specific to the used protocol, although they should of course allow the private key to be used (HSM's and smart cards generally only implement specific algorithms, for instance).

thanks so much for the detailed and insightful answer!
